# Why this multiple SQL Server join query fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table in this format:

```
PID   TIV_2011  TIV_2012     LAT         LON
123     1000      1200     20.123489   80.341245
456     1500      3000     21.341287   80.341245
789     2000      1500     21.341287   80.341245
321     1000       750     21.123641   80.238716
567     1500      2300     22.123641   80.238716
```

Question:    Write a query to print the sum of all total investment values in 2012 (TIV_2012), to a scale of 2 decimal places, for all policyholders who meet the following criteria:

1. Have the same TIV_2011 value as one or more other policyholders.
2. Are not located in the same city as another policyholder (i.e.: the latitude, longitude) attribute pair must be unique).

My Query:

```
select cast(sum(i1.tiv_2012) as decimal(12,2))
from insurance i1 join insurance i2 on i1.tiv_2011 = i2.tiv_2011
where i1.pid != i2.pid 
and i1.lat != i2.lat 
and i1.lon != i2.lon
```

Answer is  7250 which is 1200 + 3000 + 750 + 2300.

But the actual answer should be 4250 which is 1200 + 750 + 2300

This question has been answered before and the query that works fine is:

```
select cast(sum(i1.tiv_2012) as decimal(12,2)) from insurance i1 
join (select TIV_2011 from insurance group by TIV_2011 having count(*) > 1) i2 on i1.tiv_2011 = i2.TIV_2011
join (select lat,LON from insurance group by LAT,LON having COUNT(*) = 1) i3 on i1.LAT = i3.LAT and i1.LON = i3.LON
```

But can someone please let me know where or why my joins are going wrong?

Comment: This looks a LOT like homework. And what a contrived example of querying stuff. I can't read that last query as it is just a wall of text with no formatting. I don't understand the question here.

Comment: There's clearly meant to be some interaction between the two numbered clauses but it's not well spelt out and I seem to end up concluding that none of these rows should count or that things are ambiguous. Bad exercise in the first place. For instance, I can't see how both `750` and `2300` should be included by any sensible reading of the second clause.

Comment: 750 and 2300 should be included because they satisfy the condition that corresponding PIDs have same TIV_2011 values . And, their LAT and LON pairs are unique.

Comment: @ShaneBond - easy mistake to make when other `Lat`/`Lon` values were clearly different in all digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefer to write more straightforward SQL that reflects the requirements. If you want to do this via joins it can quickly get out of hand because the joins will cross multiply with each other and inflate the number of rows. In addition, the two numbered clauses require *different* conditions to express, with the second only doable with a `LEFT JOIN` that you're hoping will fail.

I'd prefer to use two `EXISTS` checks:

```
declare @t table (PID int, TIV_2011 int, TIV_2012 int, Lat decimal(8,6),Lon decimal(9,6))
insert into @t(PID,TIV_2011,TIV_2012,LAT,LON) values
(123,1000,1200,20.123489,80.341245),
(456,1500,3000,21.341287,80.341245),
(789,2000,1500,21.341287,80.341245),
(321,1000, 750,21.123641,80.238716),
(567,1500,2300,22.123641,80.238716)

select
    CONVERT(decimal(12,2),SUM(TIV_2012))
from
    @t t_keep
where
    exists (select * from @t t_other2011
       where t_keep.PID != t_other2011.PID
       and t_keep.TIV_2011 = t_other2011.TIV_2011
) and
    not exists (select * from @t t_city
       where t_keep.PID != t_city.PID and
       t_keep.Lat = t_city.Lat and
       t_keep.Lon = t_city.Lon)
```

Select rows from `@t` (`t_keep`) where (first `EXISTS`) there is another row in the table for another policyholder where we share the same `TIV_2011` value. But also (`and`) where (second `EXISTS`) there *isn't* a row in the table for another policyholder where we share the same `Lat` and `Lon` values.

This produces the 4250 value.

Answer (score 1):

You have two independent conditions but you try to use it together. Split them out using, for instance, a subquery and you will get expected result.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (
    PID         int,
    TIV_2011    int,
    TIV_2012    int,
    LAT         DECIMAL(8,6),        
    LON         DECIMAL(8,6)
) 
INSERT @Test(PID,   TIV_2011,  TIV_2012,     LAT,         LON)
VALUES
(123, 1000, 1200, 20.123489, 80.341245),
(456, 1500, 3000, 21.341287, 80.341245),
(789, 2000, 1500, 21.341287, 80.341245),
(321, 1000,  750, 21.123641, 80.238716),
(567, 1500, 2300, 22.123641, 80.238716)

select cast(sum(i1.tiv_2012) as decimal(12,2))
from @Test i1 
    join @Test i2 on i1.tiv_2011 = i2.tiv_2011
        AND i1.pid != i2.pid 
where 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM @Test
        WHERE LAT = i1.lat 
            and LON = i1.lon
            AND PID != i1.pid
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is no task where I would join at all.

```
select sum(tiv_2012)
from insurance i
where exists
(
  select * 
  from mytable other 
  where other.pid <> i.pid
  and other.tiv_2011 = i.tiv_2011
)
and not exists
(
  select * 
  from mytable other 
  where other.pid <> i.pid
  and other.lat = i.lat
  and other.lon = i.lon
);
```

I know this doesn't answer your question what is exactly wrong with your joins. In my opinion it's the approach to even use joins here, when you only want to look up other rows in the table. For looking up records we have `EXISTS` and `IN` and criteria goes to the `WHERE` clause as it should.

Comment: There is no other table: the point is to compare to other investors in the same table.

Comment: @Dan R.: What other table are you talking about? I haven't mentioned any and there is none in my query. Or were you answering some comment that was deleted after you wrote yours?

Answer (score 0):

your this line is different and doesn't make sense.

```
i1.pid != i2.pid
```

That doesn't need to be there.

Comment: I think the purpose of that line is to avoid matching an investor with himself. However, you're right that it's not needed, because we already avoid matching investors in the same city, and every investor is in the same city as himself.
(Hi Omkar, and welcome to StackOverflow!)